# Issue: Elements of an array are switching places on refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

[image: So, in my admin dashboard, I'm calculating the revenue, and I basically have an array with the last two months and their revenue]

[image: But when a refresh the page a few times, the elements in the array change and so does the revenue. Btw I'm getting this income from my api.]

[image: This is the backend]

[image: And this is the frontend]

[image: Also when I'm trying to fetch the revenue for a particular product, for some reason, it fetches th whole revenue.]

So, in my admin dashboard, I'm calculating the revenue, and I basically have an array with the last two months and their revenue

But when a refresh the page a few times, the elements in the array change and so does the revenue. Btw I'm getting this income from my api.

Also when I'm trying to fetch the revenue for a particular product, for some reason, it fetches the whole revenue.

Comment: if you have code to share please don't use pictures showing your ide just paste it here in a code fragment and possibly as isolated as possible to highlight the exact issue you are trying to address

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that your API gets the data in random order. Check the data you receive from your API. I think the array will have a different order on different requests.

Also, you should post code in `code blocks`, not images.